# Rudin 2.36 assumption?

Tags: real-analysis

*I know this has been asked before but my problem is not the proof it self but the conclusion that we draw.*

**Theorem**. If $ \{K_\alpha\} $ is a collection of compact subsets of a metric space $X$ such that the intersection of every finite subcollection of $\{K_\alpha\} $ is nonempty, then $\cap K_\alpha$ is nonempty.

*Proof*: Fix a member $K_1$ of $\{K_\alpha\}$ and put $G_\alpha=K_\alpha^c$. **Assume that no point of $K_1$ belongs to every $K_\alpha$.** Then the sets $G_\alpha$ form an open cover of $K_1$; and since $K_1$ is compact, there are finitely many indices  $\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n$ such that $K_1\subset \cup_{i=1...n} G_{\alpha_i}$. But this means that $K_1\cap K_{\alpha_1}\cap\dots \cap K_{\alpha_n}$ is empty, **in contradiction to our hypothesis.**

How does this contradict our assumption? I can follow the proof but I fail to see what conclusion can be drawn. What is the hypothesis that this contradicts?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Because your hypothesis was *every* finite intersection is non-empty.  This is a finite intersection that *IS* empty.  That's a contradiction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theorem. If $\{K_α\}$ is a collection of compact subsets of a metric space $X$ **such that the intersection of every finite subcollection of $\{K_α\}$ is nonempty**, then $\cap K_α$ is nonempty.

> "What is the hypothesis that this contradicts?"

**That the intersection of every finite subcollection of $\{K_a\}$ is nonempty.**

That would mean  $K_1 \cap K_2 \cap ...... \cap K_{\alpha_n}$ is not empty.

But the proof showed it was.  That's a contradiction.

Comment: So is the proof contradicting the theorem statement, or the assumption laid out in the second sentence of the proof?  I am confused about this proof being a “proof by contradiction” or “proof by contrapositive”.